# How to make an input show HEX?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a thing that can display the HEX of an `<input type="color">` but it will just stay "text" when I want to say example: #ffee00 (#ffee00 is a yellow color). This is the code that I used

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="color" id="inpur">
    <button onclick="YES()" id="button">click me</button>
    <h1 id="click">text</h1>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 2000px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("div")
        var input = document.getElementById("inpur")
        function YES() {
            div.style.backgroundColor = input.value
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                document.getElementById("button").click()
            }
        })
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 222) {
                document.getElementById("inpur").click()
                document.getElementById("click").innerHTML = 
                document.getElementById("inpur").value
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you're setting the background color in the `YES` function, you could the value to change the text.

Change the javascript to something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var txt = document.getElementById("click");
var input = document.getElementById("inpur");
function YES() {
   div.style.backgroundColor = input.value
   txt.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="color" id="inpur">
    <button onclick="YES()" id="button">click me</button>
    <h1 id="click">text</h1>
    <style>
        div {
            width: 2000px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: greenyellow;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById("div");
        var txt = document.getElementById("click");
        var input = document.getElementById("inpur");
        function YES() {
            div.style.backgroundColor = input.value
            txt.innerHTML = input.value;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Warning:

> [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated!
>
> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.
>
> You should avoid using this if possible; it's been deprecated for some time. Instead, you should use [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), if it's implemented. Unfortunately, some browsers still don't have it, so you'll have to be careful to make sure you use one which is supported on all target browsers.

---

As for what you are trying to accomplish, you can simplify your code like below:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("div");
  var input = document.getElementById("inpur");
  
  function YES() {
      div.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
      document.getElementById('click').innerHTML = input.value;
  }

  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", YES);
};
```

```css
div {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="color" id="inpur" />
    <button id="button">click me</button>
    <h1 id="click"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** By using

```
window.onload = function() { //... };
```

you can place your javascript anywhere on the page. This will ensure that all the elements on the page exist in the DOM before the functions can be triggered.